# Unhandled Navigation Error: When BaseHref is different from the current Host

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have one web app (Angular 8.0) hosted on one domain.
For normal users it is working fine. But when it comes to the Google web  caching it is throwing some error and router outlet is throwing error: Unhandled Navigation Error

App's Header & Footer is loading fine as it is included in App.component 
Only Router outlet's components are not loading.

After doing a lot research & Debugging, I found out that this issue is coming when the baseUrl is different from the current domain.
Let's say I'm opening this website in localhost:4200 port & and the baseUrl is localhost:4500 
and both servers are pointing to same directory, so there are no chances of missing any of the files.

So this exact scenario happens when google tries to cache my app's page
Consider google's domain is http://webcache.googleusercontent.com and it's trying different domain called: www.xyz.com

I'm attaching the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: baseHref should be "/" so it grab the current domain, dont set it manually

Comment: saying "don't set it" isn't an answer.